update string value, using file content
The incoming csv-file has the following schema:
 latitude;longtitude
 90.232;24.244

I need to generate flow file, by updating incoming schema with new field "json".
Expected outcoming schema is:
latitude;longtitude;json
90.232;24.244;"{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[90.232,24.244]}"

So I need to extract latitude and longtitude values and put them into json (represented as string value).
For this aim I used UpdateRecord with Properties:

/json value is:
  {"type":"Point","coordinates":[${\latitude},${\longtitude}]}

Also I tried:
 {"type":"Point","coordinates":[${latitude},${longtitude}]}

But the output is:
 latitude;longtitude;json
 90.232;24.244;"{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[,]}"

So nothing is put to coordinates "placeholders".
Can anybody help me?

Use a QueryRecord:

CSVReader (separator: ;)
CSVRecordSetWriter (separator: ;)
add-field (dynamic property):

SELECT latitude, longtitude, 
'{"type":"Point","coordinates":[' || latitude || ',' || longtitude || ']}' AS json 
FROM FLOWFILE

input
latitude;longtitude
90.232;24.244

output
latitude;longtitude;json
90.232;24.244;"{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[90.232,24.244]}"

